# ONNX model inference produces different results for the same input

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, onnx, onnxruntime

I'm testing the ONNX model with one identical input for multiple inference calls, but it produces different results every time?

For details, please refer to the below Colab script.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1cBd0MkQ804FXjWtOME1EB1-UiTXe1elp#scrollTo=bRLuTOjO2YQU

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected, as ONNX does not provide deterministic computations ([details](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/issues/7642#issuecomment-842583213)).

The flag `SessionOptions.use_deterministic_compute` is used for ONNX training, but inference is never stable.
The [conversion script](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/blob/v1.10.0/onnxruntime/python/tools/transformers/convert_to_onnx.py) provides a number of tests with configurable absolute and relative error.